# Collection-Property in Domain-Object - when to use?

Tags: oop

I have difficulties to model domain classes when it comes to one-to-many relationships.

Most search results talk specifically about DDD and the so called Aggregate Root. For example an Order class with order items.

In my concrete scenario I have a "Report" class, which can have references to other domain objects. The property "References" is the issue:

```
{
  "Id": "someReportId",
  "References":
  [
    {
      "ObjectType": "Machine",
      "ObjectId": "someMachineId"
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "Address",
      "ObjectId": "someAddressId"
    }
  ],
  "Answers": 
  {
    "question1": 42,
    "question2": "some answer"
  }
}
```

To me it made sense to model "References" as Property of the Domain-Object. The first consumer of my API had no problems with it.

The second consumer however needs to save and delete each "Reference" individually. My CRUD-Service only lets you save or delete a whole "Report"-Object.

For that reason I deleted the Property and moved it into a seperate service. But I'm afraid I don't see the line when I can use collection properties. Is there some rule of thumb?

Comment: If the elements of the collection do not have their own identifiers---that is, they are 'value' objects---they must be part of a collection held within the main object. For example, a `Contact` object that has a collection of `Address` elements but each address does not need to be individually identifiable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The elements are stored as a composite key in the database. The first "Reference" would be: "someReportId" + "Machine" + "someMachineId". These 3 PK Columns are the only columns. Would that suggest being a value object? so was my initial idea right, to model it as a collection property?

Comment: If their identity depends on that of the parent object---which I think they are in this case---they should be value objects, even if they actually have keys in storage. The identity at runtime is the important factor.